# Codeigniter pagination error

Tags: codeigniter, pagination

I am doing pagination in in my page, but I am getting error like this.

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: Home::$login_model
>
> Filename: controllers/home.php
>
> Line Number: 41
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function getDet() on a non-object in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\picasso\new_design\photo_frame\application\controllers\home.php
>   on line 41

This is my code

**Model:**

```
function getDet(){
$query_str = "SELECT * FROM frame";

$result = $this->db->query($query_str);
return $result;

}
```

**Controller:**

```
public function frame1()
    {
    $things = $this->login_model->getDet();
    $total_rows = $things->num_rows();

    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $config['base_url'] = base_url() . 'home/';
    $config['total_rows'] = '$total_rows';
    $config['per_page'] = '1';

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $this->view_data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
    $this->view_data['things'] = $things;

    $this->load->model('login_model');
    $data1['wood']=$this->login_model->getDetails('wood');
    $this->load->view('frame1',$data1);
}
```

**View:**

```
<div>

    <?php if($wood!=""||$wood!=null){foreach($wood as $row){  ?>
<div class="frm1" style="border:1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); background-color: rgb(244, 244, 244);list-style-type:none; float:left; display:inline; padding:20px;">
<img src="<?php echo base_url()."uploads/frame/icon/".$row['iconimage'];?>" style="cursor:pointer" class="changemount" data-id="<?php echo base_url()."uploads/frame/".$row['frameimage'];?>" 
data-price="<?php echo $row['price'];?>" data-thick="<?php echo $row['thickness'];?>" data-change="0" data-w="515" data-h="356" data-ch="385" data-cw="554" /></div>
<?php }}  ?>

    </div>
    <?php echo $pagination; ?>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to load the model, before using it.

```
public function frame1() {
    $this->load->model('login_model'); //You have to load this model, before use it
    $things = $this->login_model->getDet(); $total_rows = $things->num_rows();

    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $config['base_url'] = base_url() . 'home/';
    $config['total_rows'] = '$total_rows';
    $config['per_page'] = '1';

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $this->view_data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
    $this->view_data['things'] = $things;


    $data1['wood']=$this->login_model->getDetails('wood');
    $this->load->view('frame1',$data1);
}
```

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: pagination
Filename: views/frame1.php
Line Number: 87

Comment: <?php echo $pagination; ?>

Comment: <?php if($wood!=""||$wood!=null){foreach($wood as $row){  ?>
 <div class="frm1" style=" background-color: rgb(244, 244, 244);list-style-type:none; float:left; display:inline; padding:20px;">
<img src="<?php echo base_url()."uploads/frame/icon/".$row['iconimage'];?>" style="cursor:pointer" class="changemount" data-id="<?php echo base_url()."uploads/frame/".$row['frameimage'];?>" 
data-price="<?php echo $row['price'];?>" data-thick="<?php echo $row['thickness'];?>" data-change="0" data-w="515" data-h="356" data-ch="385" data-cw="554" /></div>
<?php }}  ?>

Comment: Seems like you´re not passing your **$pagination** resource from controller to view. Notice you are saving the $pagination variable in **$view_data** array: 
`$this->view_data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();`
And you are passing the $data1 array to your view:
`$this->load->view('frame1',$data1);`
You have to save the $pagination variable in the same array you pass to view:
`$this->data1['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();`
Same with **$things**, if you are using it in view:
`$this->data1['things'] = $things;`

Answer (score 0):

undefined login_model, means you call the model without loading it, add this to your `_construct` in controller

```
$this->load->model("model_name");
```

and also in your view you miss something important, to execute your code in loop do the code below

```
//add the ->result() in your var $wood
foreach($wood->result() as $row)
```

this will fix your error